# Font for cutting?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

I want to print a text inside a box. I mean the text should be cut out (see through). Example:
[image]

As you can see the parts in "o" and "e" cant float.. it needs some kind of a support. Also the top triangle in the M can't be printed without a support.
Here is something I found, I think this is what I need:

[image]

Can you recommend me a font or some app to make these fonts printable the way I need it?

The software I use is Simplify3D and all the free ones like cura.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a quick search using The Google with the terms "stencil font." There were too many results to list here and the first link I clicked on provided some seriously ugly fonts. Stencil fonts by definition will result in supported center pieces. Windows has a native font named, surprisingly enough, Stencil which does the same, but it's not quite as imaginative as the ones found using The Google.

Here's an example from Font Squirell:

Octin Prison

[image: Octin Prison Font]

How about something a bit more bizarre from the same location:

VanBerger Font

[image: VanBerger]

Comment: A stencil font for 3D printing would minimize the connectors that break up the character. These fonts have unnecessary breaks in characters like L, J, Y, 7, etc., which would print just fine and be strong enough without those breaks.